# Sakai 11 SQL migration without autoddl

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, sakai

Is there a way to migrate / create the Sakai 11 database without doing it during installation with the autoddl tool, i.e., manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Some parts of Sakai have SQL scripts that are run when Sakai is started up and `auto.ddl` is set to `true`. However other parts just use hibernate to create their schema as a result there's no single script to create a schema for Sakai.

For migrating between versions Sakai uses manual SQL migration scripts which you can find here: https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai-reference/tree/master/docs/conversion

Comment: Thanks. Seems like Sakai lacks a lot of documentation when it comes to bring it up for any project...

Comment: Right, you have to bring up the initial database with the auto.ddl but then you can turn it off and just use the conversion scripts. You could bring up Sakai with auto.ddl on a test database, do a full SQL dump and then just load it. This might save some time if you were using it the database in testing or something.